# Alpha mixing property of a $\mathbb{R}^d$ valued Stochastic Process

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, time-series, mixing

In statistics and probability literature, a strictly stationary stochastic process $\{X_t\}\in\mathbb{R}$ is called  $\alpha$-mixing if

$\alpha(n)=\sup_{A\in\mathcal{F}_{-\infty}^{0}, B\in\mathcal{F}_{n}^{\infty}}|P(A)P(B)-P(AB)|\longrightarrow 0$

as $n\rightarrow 0$ where $\mathcal{F}_{a}^{b}$ denotes the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\{X_t; i\leq t\leq j\}$.

Let us now consider an $\mathbb{R}^d$-valued (stationary) stochastic process $\{Z_t\}$ defined as $\{Z_t\}:=\{Z_{1t},Z_{2t},...,Z_{dt}\}^{T}$. I was wondering if the process $\{Z_t\}$ being mixing would imply that its marginal processes $\{Z_{it}\}$ $\forall i$ being mixing or vice versa..

I understand this should be rather straightforward, but could not rigorously provide a proof with this.. This is not a homework, just personal curiosity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us denote by $\alpha(n)$ the $n$th $\alpha$-mixing coefficient of $\{X_t\}$.

If $f\colon\mathbb R^d\to\mathbb R$ is a Borel-measurable function then $\alpha'(n)\leqslant \alpha(n)$, where $\alpha'(n)$ is the $n$th $\alpha$-mixing coefficient of $\{f(X_t)\}$. This because $\sigma\{f(X_i),a\leqslant i\leqslant b\}\subset\sigma\{X_i,a\leqslant i\leqslant b\}$.

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/322398/is-the-product-of-two-mixing-random-variables-also-mixing) is a question about a partial converse.

Comment: Thanks very much Davide! Could you please kindly provide me with a sketch proof for this? (or perhaps recommend a book that covers this?) Also, I was wondering if the converse of the statement would hold. I.e. If $\{Z_{it}\}$ is mixing for all $i$, would $\{Z_t\}:=\{Z_{1t},Z_{2t},...,Z_{dt}\}$ be mixing as well? Many thanks in advance..

Comment: @JohnK Braley's book is a good reference, there is also Doukhan's book. See edit for the other questions.

Comment: I am very sorry for the delayed response, thanks so much for your help!

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: So, this tells us that for an alpha mixing random vector the marginals will also be alpha mixing. I am no wondering about the converse, is it true that if two random vectors are alpha mixing $X_t$ and $Y_t$ is the stacked random vector $(X_t, Y_t)$ also alpha mixing. I can see that the answer Davide referenced shows that the product is alpha mixing if we additionally assume the processes are independent.